# Read plist from URL into NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to do read a PLIST from URL to a NSMutableDictionary.

Code before

```
autos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[autos addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Auto 1", @"name", @"Auto.png", @"image", @"Klassiker", @"description" , nil]];
```

This works. But now I want to use a PLIST. And I am trying this, this way:

```
autos = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9358444/auto.plist"]]];
```

Thanks.

PLIST http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9358444/auto.plist

Comment: Problem is app crashes if trying to use PLIST and I open the row which contains auto in the tableview.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide the crash log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property list contains a dictionary, but you're trying to use it to instantiate an array. Do this instead:

```
NSMutableDictionary *autos = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                                 [NSURL urlWithString:@"http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9358444/auto.plist"]];
```

Comment: OK. Thanks. But then I have autos in a NSMutable Dictionary. I need it for further things in a NSMutableArray.

Comment: So add it to a mutable array using `-addObject:`.

Comment: Thanks. I did so: NSMutableDictionary *cars = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                                 [NSURL urlWithString:@"http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9358444/auto.plist"]]; [autos addobject:cars] but if I now go the tableview of autos there is a row but it is emtpy and if I click on this empty row it crashes with  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSPlaceholderString initWithString:]: nil argument'

Comment: @halloway4b You can use the debugger to verify the contents of the array after adding your dictionary. If the dictionary is in the array, the rest is a separate problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to the site, I'm still not sure how to add comments to the OP. Load it into a dictionary first then transfer it into a mutable array

Comment: How can I transfer it? How can I put the information in the Dictionary in an Array?

Comment: [theArray addObject: theDictionary] - can't really do much more than that. since dictionary is key-pair, where as array is index based.